Why do i keep getting "Argument 1 missing or nil" when there are no parameters
i am quite new at coding and this might be a easy fix, but like i said, im a new coder so dont judge me if i do some silly mistakes, anyways i am making gui where after you click play, it enables your controls, and so that it will not work again if you reset, but simply choosing "ResetOnSpawn" to false wont work, and my current code keeps getting the error "Argument 1 missing or nil"
Please help.
Play button script
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local players = Players.LocalPlayer

    local cc = game.Workspace.CurrentCamera -- this part is for main menu camera, its useless for this problem
    local pc = game.Workspace.Camera
    local Cams = cc.CFrame

    cc.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Scriptable
    cc.CFrame = pc.CFrame
    local function ok()
        cc.CFrame = pc.CFrame
    end
    ok()



    local replicated = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
    local remote = replicated:WaitForChild("WaveTrigger")
    local function triggering ()
        remote:FireServer()
    end

    local playerscripts = players:WaitForChild("PlayerScripts")
    local Playermodules = require(playerscripts:WaitForChild("PlayerModule"))
    local controls = Playermodules:GetControls()
    controls:Disable()
    local starting = replicated:WaitForChild("ControlEnabling")

    script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function() --when mouse clicks gui, it does this script
        triggering()
        script.Parent.Parent.Transparency = 1
        script.Parent.Transparency = 1
        local fond = script.Parent.Parent:FindFirstChild("GameLabel") --gui stuff
        if fond then
            fond.Transparency = 1
        end
        starting:FireServer()
        cc.CameraType = Enum.CameraType.Track
        cc.CFrame = Cams
        script:Destroy() --ends the script so that if player resets it wont repeat
        
    end)

Fires this server script
local replicated = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remote = replicated:WaitForChild("ControlEnabling")
remote.OnServerEvent:Connect(function()
    local controlEnabling = replicated:WaitForChild("ActualEnabling")
    controlEnabling:FireClient() --The Error
end)



and that fires this script
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local players = Players.LocalPlayer


local playerscripts = players:WaitForChild("PlayerScripts")
local Playermodules = require(playerscripts:WaitForChild("PlayerModule"))
local controlling = Playermodules:GetControls()

local replicated = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")
local remote = replicated:WaitForChild("ActualEnabling")

remote.OnClientEvent:Connect(function()
    controlling:Enable() --enables the controls
    print("controls were enabled")

end)


Also for anyone wondering why i didnt just put the controls:Enable() at the play button script, it is because if i do script:Destroy() then it will also disable the controls
